# Python Telegram Chat Bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I got a problem in writing code for my telegram customer service chat. Apparently, let me confess my little knowledge in the field. Can I get open source code for telegram chatbot which automatically forwards the messages sent to it to a specific id (my-id)? Thank you...I'm badly in need of this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install pytelegrambotapi (`pip install pytelegrambotapi`) and then you'll be able to use somthing like that:

```
import telebot

token = "hd9ouhs98h928w982982"
your_id = "321321321321"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message): 
    bot.send_message(your_id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.infinity_polling()
```